# Losing Data in NSMutableArray during Loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, nsmutablearray

I am trying to create a NSMutableArray so I can populate a map. But immediately after "[row removeAllObjects];" it removes all of the objects in the "layer" array also.

```
NSMutableArray *row = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *layer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *all = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

int blockType = 0;
for (int y = 0; y<10; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x<10; x++) {
        for (int z = 0; z<10; z++) {
            if (y<5) blockType = 0;
            else blockType = arc4random() % 2 + 1;
            [row addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:blockType]];
        }
        [layer addObject:row];
        [row removeAllObjects];
    }
    [all addObject:layer];
    [layer removeAllObjects];
}
```

is this because

```
        [layer addObject:row];
        [row removeAllObjects];
```

are being performed at the same time? If so, how do I carry out the actions one after another?

If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's because when you do addObject:row you actually add a pointer to *that* version of `row` to your `layer`.  Then, when you do `[row removeAllObjects]`, you remove everything from the `row` you just added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
[layer addObject:[row copy]];
```

Comment: Expanding on this answer, the problem is that you are adding a reference to the same row object that you are then immediately removing all of the objects from. Using copy creates a *new* row.

Comment: Or, better, simply allocate a new array into `row` for each interation.

Comment: I don't think this works, because you have the same problem with `[layer removeAllObjects]`.

Comment: Though this might be the solution to the problem, please take a minute and clarify your answer. Why is this the solution and what is the problem with the authors approach?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding `row` to `layer`, but then you're emptying it.

I understand why you are doing this, as you want to re-use both `row` and `layer`. However that's not how it works in Objective-C, as variables are just references (C pointers) to objects.

What you need to do is to create `all` outside the loops, and re-create `row` and `layer` inside the inner loops. You can re-use the variables, but the underlying objects need to change.

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *all = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *row;
NSMutableArray *layer;

int blockType = 0;

for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
    layer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        row = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
            if (y < 5)
                blockType = 0;
            else
                blockType = arc4random() % 2 + 1;

            [row addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:blockType]];
        }

        [layer addObject: row];
    }

    [all addObject: layer];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `NSMutableArray *row = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` to just after `for (int x = 0; x<10; x++) {`, and delete `[row removeAllObjects];` entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You create a problematic program structure, and it bites you in the behind.

```
for (int z = 0; z<10; z++) {
    if (y<5) blockType = 0;
    else blockType = arc4random() % 2 + 1;
    [row addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:blockType]];
}
[layer addObject:row];
[row removeAllObjects];
```

This code is supposed to create an array with 10 numbers and add it to the array "layer". But that's not what it does. The array has been created a lot earlier. And add the end, it empties out the array to be ready for the next iteration. That's an awful structure. The correct structure would be:

```
NSMutableArray* row = [NSMutableArray array];        
for (int z = 0; z<10; z++) {
    if (y<5) blockType = 0;
    else blockType = arc4random() % 2 + 1;
    [row addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:blockType]];
}
[layer addObject:row];
```

This does exactly what it is supposed to do: Create an array, fill it with data, add it to layer. No reliance on previous and following code. The complete working code is:

```
NSMutableArray *all = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int y = 0; y<10; y++) {
    NSMutableArray *layer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int x = 0; x<10; x++) {
        NSMutableArray *row = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int z = 0; z<10; z++) {
            int blockType = y < 5 ? 0 : arc4random() % 2 + 1;
            [row addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:blockType]];
        }
        [layer addObject:row];
    }
    [all addObject:layer];
}
```

Well, someone else typed quicker. Which is even better, because you see twice an identical program structure, with almost identical code. That's because the task is clear, and there is exactly one way how any experienced programmer would structure the code.